# How to make Firefox sync reliable: new bookmarks are lost and old bookmarks reappear in unsorted

Tags: firefox, sync, bookmarks, firefox-sync

I am trying to synchronise my bookmarks between a PC and two Macs using Firefox sync. My bookmarks (2000+) are arranged into a heirachy of folders. After sync, old folders that have been deleted re-appear and many bookmarks are duplicated into unsorted bookmarks.

I have Firefox 33.0.1.

I have bookmarks, preferences and addons set to sync.

Sometimes when organizing bookmarks, I turn sync off or it locks up syncing all the time.

Googling for problems with Firefox sync is no help at all. Is no-one using Firefox sync? Is everyone using Xmarks? (I dropped Xmarks as it is unreliable in Firefox and Safari).

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to make Firefox sync work reliably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have dropped Xmarks for the same reason as you have. Same with Firefox Sync. Then I put my whole Firefox profile in Dropbox (or any other sync service really) and was happy since then.

Comment: I made this an answer rather than comment since Xmarks and Firefox Sync services are unreliable for years (at least for me).

Comment: Good suggestion. I will try it. I have been exporting my whole bookmarks collection to dropbox, but it is a poor solution.

Comment: Firefox Sync and Xmarks are still unreliable for me. What a shame that they can't get it right :/ I've started using Eversync which seems solid.